# server sent event problem in parameter in each click

Tags: ajax, server-sent-events

i had a problem in update server sent event

i click 3 times first time id = 1 second id = 2 third = 3

output = 1 , 1 ,1 ,1 , 1 , 1 (first click)

output = 1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 2 (second click)

output = 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 (third click)

i want the particular id that user click only 
so any help

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-menu .online ul li',function(e){

     var id = $(this).attr('id');

     var ev = '';

             ev = new EventSource("/ajaxpages/insertmessage.php?id="+id+" ");

             ev.onmessage = function(data) {

                 console.log(data['data']);

             }; }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP ! it's JavaScript !

Comment: i want to reset server sent request not count every thing from start !

Comment: post your button code also .